# Update prototype's property after object creation

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.x = 1

foo = new Foo()
foo2 = new Foo()

foo2.x = 2
Foo.prototype.x = 3

console.log("foo.x = ", foo.x)
console.log("foo2.x = ", foo2.x)
```

```
=> foo.x = 3
=> foo2.x = 2
```

Two objects are created above, the `inherited property` of one object is updated, then their `prototype's property` is updated. Why does the updated object retain its own new value but the other track the `prototype's` ?

**@EDIT**

The expression above, `the inherited property of one object is updated`, seems misleading in the above context.

In fact, a `shadow property` will be created on the `object`, when a locally non-existing  `property` is set, even if the `prototype` already contains it. In this case, the `prototype's properties` are ready-only from the standpoint of the `object`. Afterwards, this `local shadow property` has the immediate right to be accessed.

Comment: Because Javascript works like that. If a property isn't found in the object, then it's searched through the object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the updated object retain its own new value but the other track the prototype's ?

Because the `x` property is directly set on `foo2` and **shadows** the `x` property of the prototype.

Do `console.dir(foo2)` and see for yourself:

```
Foo
  x: 2
  __proto__: Foo
     constructor: function Foo() {}
     x: 3
     __proto__: Object
```

Whereas `console.dir(foo)` shows:

```
Foo
  __proto__: Foo
     constructor: function Foo() {}
     x: 3
     __proto__: Object
```

When you are trying to access a property, always the value closest to the object in the prototype chain will be returned.

The exact algorithm can be found in [§8.12.2 of the ECMAScript 5.1 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.2).

Comment: It's quite handy! `console.log` usually shows the value in some appropriate, human-readable format, but `console.dir` seems to always convert the argument to an object and lists all properties and shows the inheritance. It certainly helps to inspect values properly.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will only look to the prototype to resolve a property call if it is not specifically defined on the current instance.

Since `.x` is defined for foo2 as `2`, it looks no further for the value.
However, for foo, `.x` is not defined on the instance, so it looks to the prototype, and gets 3.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question, anyway the answer is simple: because the `foo2` object has a property named `x` which has its own value and is not inherited from the prototype. If you want to access the prototype value you should do `foo1.constructor.prototype.x`. You have to imagine the structure like this:

- Foo
- Foo.prototype

  - Foo.prototype.x

The variables look like this:

- foo = {}
- foo2 = {x:2}

If JS doesn't find the `x` property in the object then it will look inside the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `foo.x`, so it takes the default `prototype` value, which at the time of the `.log()`, is `3`.

If you go

```
foo.x = 10
foo2.x = 2
Foo.prototype.x = 3
```

...then check `foo.x`, it's 10, since it's been explicitly overridden.

As a corollary, if you don't set `foo2.x`, it will also be `3`:

```
...
//foo2.x = 2
Foo.prototype.x = 3
...
```

If things didn't work like that, it would mean the `.prototype` property would be read-only after instantiation, so you'd have different versions of the default flying around depending on when you instantiated and/or changed the property.  No fun.

When you explicitly override it, you're aware of when and why it's changed.  Otherwise, the current setting of `.prototype` is used.